# Understanding this expression for tp

Tags: functions

tp=inf{t>0|N(t)>N(0)}

At the moment, I understand that tp is equal to infinity for all t > 0 given N(t) is greater than N(0) but I am not confident if I am thinking correctly. I will appreciate a better explanation for this. Thanks!

Comment: inf is not in infinity. It stands for infimum.

Comment: $t_p$ is the first time when $N(t)$ is strictly bigger than $N(0)$.

Comment: @geetha290krm: thanks for clarifying that. This is the first time I am hearing this word. I will look it up. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Surb: Thank you for saying it in simple words. This equation makes more sense now. I believe I understand it much better now.